# How to stop execute code when window is popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function:

```
    this.foo = function (old, newVal) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        var f = "ddd";
        var oldval = old;
        var newVal = newVal;
    }
```

As you can see window popup called inside the function.

Here the definition of the window:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
      <!-- Modal content-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to popup the window and only after user click "YES" or "NO" on the popup window this rows executed in `foo()` function(i.e I need to make delay on popup):

```
    var f = "ddd";
    var oldval = old;
    var newVal = newVal;
```

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: How can you popup a window ONLY if the user has clicked in the window you have not yet popped?

Comment: Just make a second function and have it get called by the click on yes/no. The code that handles that click shouldn't be in the same function as the code that shows the popup modal.

Answer (score 1):

There should be different approaches to this, below is one example to give you an idea. Basically you can use the modal's `shown` and `hidden` events to achieve that.

Suppose there is a button on your modal with id `btn_ok`, then in your `shown` event callback, bind to that button's onclick event and assign value to a variable which will be evaluated in the `hidden` event callback (when the modal disappears).

```
this.foo = function (old, newVal) {
        var m = $('#myModal');
        var btn_ok_selected = false;

        m.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            var btn_ok = m.find('#btn_ok');

            btn_ok.click(function() {
                btn_ok_selected = true;
            });
        });

        m.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
            if (btn_ok_selected === true) {
                var f = "ddd";
                var oldval = old;
                var newVal = newVal;

                // more code here

            }
        });

        m.modal('show');

    }
```